# Spark standalone cluster - Output file stored in temporary directory in worker

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am new to Spark and I have a Spark standalone cluster with 2 workers -

- Master and one slave thread run on a single machine -- Machine 1
- Another slave running on a separate machine -- Machine 2

I am running a spark shell in the 2nd machine that reads a file from hdfs and does some calculations on them and stores the result in hdfs.

This is how I read the file in spark shell -

```
val file = sc.textFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/table.csv")
```

And this is how I write the result back to a file -

```
finalRDD.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/output_file")
```

When I run the code, it runs in the cluster and the job succeeds with each worker processing roughly half of the input file. I am also able to see the records processed in the webUI.

But when I check HDFS in the 2nd machine, I find only one part of the output file.

The other part is stored in the hdfs in the 1st machine. But even the part is not actually present in the proper hdfs location and is instead stored in a _temporary directory

In machine 2 -

```
root@worker:~# hadoop fs -ls ./output_file
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup          0 2015-07-06 16:12 output_file/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup     984337 2015-07-06 16:12 output_file/part-00000
```

In machine 1 -

```
root@spark:~# hadoop fs -ls ./output_file/_temporary/0/task_201507061612_0003_m_000001
-rw-r--r--   3 root supergroup     971824 2015-07-06 16:12 output_file/_temporary/0/
task_201507061612_0003_m_000001/part-00001
```

I have a couple of questions -

1. Shouldn't both parts be on the worker 2 ( since the hdfs referred to
   in the saveAsTextFile is the local hdfs) ? OR will the output be
   always split in the workers ?
2. Why is the output stored in the _temporary directory in machine 1 ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new too to spark, but in my understanding :

1. Yes you should have one single file containing all results.
2. The output your taking about is just a temporary result and should me merged in the final one.

When the job fails, it may leave temporary result. May be you have some errors in the logs ?

Comment: crv - The job is not failing and I am not able to see any errors in the logs. Both the master and the slaves are reporting the job as completed successfully.